# A nontrivial clique cover on a 2-colored complete graph, where no clique is of equal color.

Tags: graph-theory, contest-math

Let $K_{n}$ be a complete graph with an edge clique cover $C_{1}, C_{2}, \ldots, C_{l}$ and a coloring of $K_{n}$'s vertices with 2 colors. However, all cliques $C_{i} (1 \leq i \leq l)$ must consist of vertices with two colors. Must $l$ be equal to $1$? (i.e. are there nontrivial partitions?)

Some background: I'm a high school math olympian. I just recently formulated a quite interesting problem on edge clique cover, but after some days of exploration I'm unable to progress, even a tiny bit. Even worse, even if I do think the statement too strong to be false (it's hard to construct a counter example!), the possibility is still there.

As I'm only familiar with elementary techniques (please no linear algebra/advanced probabilistic methods), I would appreciate a solution which uses olympiad-oriented ones. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $K_n$ is a complete graph, isn't itself its own edge clique cover?

Comment: What's the definition of edge clique cover? Must they be edge disjoint?

Comment: Reply 1. Yes, that's exactly my question. Is there a covering that does not result in l = 1? (i.e. are there nontrivial coverings?)

Comment: Reply 2. Yes, edge disjoint. Not necessarily vertex disjoint (of course!)